# How to testfor and execute the effect in the single command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to do the following but not add a comparator linking the testfor to the setblock, instead I wish to have them in the same space.

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ grass /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ dirt
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot chain `testforblock` with more commands just like that, but there are other ways to do it.

#### 1. `execute`'s `detect` keyword

The [`execute`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute) command has a special `detect` keyword that allows you to do exactly what you want. It is *essentially* a `testforblock` query inside an execute.

```
execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> detect <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> <data> <command>
```

This will run `<command>` on `<entity>` only if `<block>` (with `<data>`) is present at `<x2> <y2> <z2>`<sup>1</sup>. So for your example, you want to use

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0 setblock ~ ~-1 ~ dirt
```

<sup>1) If you use tilde notation for relative coordinates, the second set of coordinates is relative to the first set (in this case the position of `@p`).</sup>

#### 2. `fill`'s `replace` option

An alternate way to do what you want to do is to use the [`fill`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#fill) command with the `replace` option (This is more limited in scope, and I only include it here for completeness):

```
fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <TileName> <dataValue> replace [replaceTileName] [replaceDataValue]
```

If both coordinate sets are identical, it will only affect a single block. So, to replace grass below the player with dirt, you can use

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ dirt 0 replace grass 0
```